# Give the power series expansion of $\log z$ about $i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I'm trying to solve the exercise 5 from page 74.

In this exercise the author asks for the radius of convergence and power series expansion of $\log z$ about $i$.

Can I use the proposition 2.5 on page 35?

[image]

When I apply this theorem I get $a_0=\frac{\pi}{2}i, a_1=\frac{1}{i}, a_2=\frac{1}{2}, a_3=\frac{-1}{3i}$, etc.

Am I right? how can I use the results of the section 2 where this exercise come from?

Similar question: [Taylor series expansion of $\log[z]$ about $z=1$ (different branches)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347036/taylor-series-expansion-of-logz-about-z-1-different-branches)

Comment: I think that $a_0=i\frac \pi 2$. The other seem to be correct (except that I should put the $i$'s in numerators).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you, I corrected my question

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1z =\frac1{i+(z-i)}=\frac1i\frac1{1-(i-z)/i}=\frac1i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i-z}{i}\right)^n$$
The radius of convergence of the series is 1 (why?) and you can integrate it term to term.

EDIT: using the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), is easy to prove that for any $r\in(0,1)$ the series is uniformly convergent in the closed disk $\{z\in\Bbb C:|z-i|\le r\}$ and it is possible to exchange integral and summation.

Comment: which theorem are you using?

Comment: @user42912, power series are uniformly convergent in discs of radius < radius of convergence.

Comment: could give a little bit more details please, thank you